# Exercises recommended for patients suffering from Carpal Tunnel Syndrome

Tags: pain, wrist, safety

I suspect that I have [CTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpal_tunnel_syndrome) (in my right hand) because of most of the symptoms (of the same) do match, and as a result, I haven't been to the gym in a week. I train regularly for 5-6 days a week with weights for building my strength and body, apart from keeping myself fit. I have the following questions provided my hunch turns out to be right after the diagnosis:

- Is it recommended to workout with heavy weights and maintain the previous workout chart, now?
- What kind of exercises and safety measures are recommended as well as forbidden, in general, for those who are suffering from CTS before as well as after [surgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexor_retinaculum_of_the_hand#Clinical_Significance)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking from anecdotal evidence, depending on the severity of the symptoms, there's no need to restrict your gym time or routine.  Again, that's going to depend on what your tolerance for pain/numbness is.  Personally, I would back off a little on the weights until you have a firm diagnosis.  The surgery is a safe and quick procedure (~20 minutes) that mostly entails snipping the ligament to decompresses the nerve(s) within the wrist. The ligament will scar over, yet, provide enough room for decompression of the nerve(s).

Going forward, PT can be prescribed, again, depending on the severity of the condition.  In most cases, using a rubber ball (on your own) to work on strengthening the wrist, hand, and forearm is typically sufficient within  a ~three week recovery.  Additionally, you may want to invest in some [hand therapy putty](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00WILCCYG) and/or [hand grip exerciser](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0178VORZ2).  Neither are required, but, could help with recovery.

As for contraindications, you should avoid any movements that press directly on the surgery site.  To help prevent that, a good pair of padded workout gloves (in the palm and lower wrist) is essential.